# Why can we use eRx in 16 bit mode, but not rRx in 32 bit mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

In x86 assembly, why can we use `eRx` in 16 bit "real mode", but we can't use `rRx` in 32 bit mode? For example:

```
BITS 16
mov bx, 1
mov eax, 2
```

will assemble and disassemble correctly. And it works, as I have disassembled the Win2k bootloader before and found references to `eax`.

However, how come there is no way, even on a 64-bit processor, in 32-bit "protected mode", you can't access `rRx`?

Comment: I'm afraid it's one of those questions where the answer is "because that's how they made it". Or from a different angle, because the operand size override is always valid but REX becomes an `inc` or `dec` outside of long mode (REX.W becomes a `dec`).

Comment: It just happens that 16-bit `mov ax,2` and 32-bit `mov eax,2` use the same instruction code. The mode the process runs in determines what will happen. Perhaps IDA isn't sure which mode the code uses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that the 64bit mode *changes* instruction decoding in one particular place - namely, to enable the prefix bytes used to indicate operand sizes of 64bit / extend register width to 64bit / extend register usage to the "new" `R8`..`R15` registers. These are different from the "alternate size prefix" (`0x66`), which is generic to x86 (independent of the CPU operating mode) and changes operand/register size from 16bit to 32bit if in 16bit mode, and vice versa from 32bit to 16bit if in 32bit mode.

The so-called `REX` prefixes are encoded as `0x40`..`0x4f` and are *only* valid as prefixes if the CPU is operating in 64bit mode. Why is that so ? Well - as said, changed instruction decoding, these opcodes actually map to one-byte versions of `inc <reg>`/`dec <reg>` in classical x86.
This is possible because of an ambiguity in the 16/32bit instruction set - `inc EAX` can be *either* `0x40` *or* `0xff 0xc0`. In 64bit mode, the instruction decoder only accepts `0xff 0xc0` for this. On the other hand, `0x40`, as indicated, becomes one of the `REX` prefixes.

Hence - these 64bit operand size prefixes *do not exist* in 16bit/32bit mode (they are `inc`/`dec` operations then ...), therefore there exists no way for 16bit/32bit x86 code to state "I'd like to do a 64bit op".

As an example, here's the assembly / opcodes for a few instructions with different operand sizes:

```
      64bit   32bit option 1   32bit option 2     instruction
=============================================================
      fe c8            fe c8               --     dec    al
   66 ff c8         66 ff c8            66 48     dec    ax
      ff c8            ff c8               48     dec    eax
   48 ff c8               --               --     dec    rax
```

As you can see, 64bit knows no one-byte version of `dec eax`, but instead it knows `0x48` as (one of several) instruction prefix(es) saying "make this a 64bit op".

Answer (score 4):

You can't access 64-bit registers in non-64-bit modes by design, CPU design.

You can access 32-bit registers in 16-bit modes by design as well. You do this by using the special instruction prefixes called *operand size prefix* (`0x66`) and *address size prefix* (`0x67`).

There are no special instruction prefixes to reach 64-bit registers in non-64-bit modes.

There was not enough opcode/prefix coding space left in 32-bit mode to add that in, unlike when 386 extended 286 there were some unused bytes for prefixes.

The `0x4?` REX prefixes that are needed to specify 64-bit operand-size in 64-bit mode are `inc`/`dec` instructions in 32-bit and 16-bit mode.  AMD64 had to change the meaning of some bytes to make room for the prefixes they wanted to.  The same change to 32-bit mode would not be compatible with existing binaries.

Comment: These prefixes in non-64 bit modes switch only from 16-bit to 32-bit or the other way around. By design.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you were using a 80286, then it would not work!  The computer you are using is a 32bit CPU which has both 16bit and 32bit registers but NOT 64bit registers.  It would work on a 64bit cpu also.